# How to read Excel XML (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I wonder if there is an easy way to read Excel 2010 XML?
 This XML has a different structure than I used to read.

Especially ss:index attribute (ss:Index**="7") makes things a bit more complicated

**EDIT**:
To explain better:

- I have file with XML extension which can be easily opened in Excel
- I'm looking a way to read this sheet programically (eg copy to DataTable)
- Noticed this is not common XML I used to work
- XML defines fields on the begining, than use ROW, CELL and DATA tags
- What surprised me is when there are eg 3 fields (cells) but 2nd field doesn't have value this field is 'skipped' in XML, but 3rd field has some additional 'index' attribute eg: ss:Index**="3" (which indicates that even it is on 2nd position right index should be "3"

fragment of example XML

```
      <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Johny</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">NY</Data></Cell>
```

Comment: Well, I can read it in your post.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Looking easy way to let's say convert Excel file stored as XML to DataTable. I know how process XML however I've problem with ss:Index attribute (used when cell is empty)

Comment: It might help to explain *that* problem then.

Comment: Added more detailed explanation then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I've finally found solution from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet#xx

Below sample code little adopted to my needs.

```
public static class XMLtoDataTable {
  private static ColumnType getDefaultType() {
    return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
}

        struct ColumnType {
            public Type type;
            private string name;
            public ColumnType(Type type) { this.type = type; this.name = type.ToString().ToLower(); }
            public object ParseString(string input) {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    return DBNull.Value;
                switch (type.ToString()) {
                    case "system.datetime":
                        return DateTime.Parse(input);
                    case "system.decimal":
                        return decimal.Parse(input);
                    case "system.boolean":
                        return bool.Parse(input);
                    default:
                        return input;
                }
            }
        }


    private static ColumnType getType(XmlNode data) {
    string type = null;
    if (data.Attributes["ss:Type"] == null || data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value == null)
        type = "";
    else
        type = data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value;

    switch (type) {
        case "DateTime":
            return new ColumnType(typeof(DateTime));
        case "Boolean":
            return new ColumnType(typeof(Boolean));
        case "Number":
            return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
        case "":
            decimal test2;
            if (data == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.InnerText) || decimal.TryParse(data.InnerText, out test2)) {
                return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
            } else {
                return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
            }
        default://"String"
            return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
    }
}

    public static DataSet ImportExcelXML (string fileName, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType) {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( fileName);
        Stream st = (Stream) sr.BaseStream;
        return ImportExcelXML( st, hasHeaders, autoDetectColumnType);
    }

    private static DataSet ImportExcelXML(Stream inputFileStream, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType) {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(inputFileStream));
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        nsmgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        foreach (XmlNode node in 
          doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ss:Worksheet", nsmgr)) {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(node.Attributes["ss:Name"].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            XmlNodeList rows = node.SelectNodes("ss:Table/ss:Row", nsmgr);
            if (rows.Count > 0) {

                //*************************
                //Add Columns To Table from header row
                //*************************
                List<ColumnType> columns = new List<ColumnType>();
                int startIndex = 0;
                if (hasHeaders) {
                    foreach (XmlNode data in rows[0].SelectNodes("ss:Cell/ss:Data", nsmgr)) {
                        columns.Add(new ColumnType(typeof(string)));//default to text
                        dt.Columns.Add(data.InnerText, typeof(string));
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                }
                //*************************
                //Update Data-Types of columns if Auto-Detecting
                //*************************
                if (autoDetectColumnType && rows.Count > 0) {
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[startIndex].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++) {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex = 
                              int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        ColumnType autoDetectType = 
                          getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count) {
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + 
                              actualCellIndex.ToString(), autoDetectType.type);
                            columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        } else {
                            dt.Columns[actualCellIndex].DataType = autoDetectType.type;
                            columns[actualCellIndex] = autoDetectType;
                        }

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }
                }
                //*************************
                //Load Data
                //*************************
                for (int i = startIndex; i < rows.Count; i++) {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[i].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++) {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex = int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        XmlNode data = cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr);

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count) {
                            for (int ii = dt.Columns.Count; ii < actualCellIndex; ii++) {
                                dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(), typeof(string));columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                            } // ii
                            ColumnType autoDetectType = 
                               getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(), 
                                           typeof(string));
                            columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        }
                        if (data != null)
                            row[actualCellIndex] = data.InnerText;

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }


}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! This works flawless with xml generated by CarlosAq XML Excel Writer Library after i changed the doubles (ss:) to singles (s:). Saved me hours of work! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is for all intents and purposes an excellent solution, however be careful of duplicate column names, this code does not account for them and needs to be modified in case they are encountered.

Answer (score 3):

Even without coulmn type its working fine too. thanks !!!

have sample for without coulmn type:

```
    private static DataSet ImportExcelXML(Stream inputFileStream, bool hasHeaders)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(inputFileStream));
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

    nsmgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    foreach (XmlNode node in
      doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ss:Worksheet", nsmgr))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(node.Attributes["ss:Name"].Value);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        XmlNodeList rows = node.SelectNodes("ss:Table/ss:Row", nsmgr);
        if (rows.Count > 0)
        {

            //*************************
            //Add Columns To Table from header row
            //*************************
            List<ColumnType> columns = new List<ColumnType>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            if (hasHeaders)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode data in rows[0].SelectNodes("ss:Cell/ss:Data", nsmgr))
                {
                    columns.Add(new ColumnType(typeof(string)));//default to text
                    dt.Columns.Add(data.InnerText, typeof(string));
                }
                startIndex++;
            }
            //*************************
            //Update Data-Types of columns if Auto-Detecting
            //*************************
            if (rows.Count > 0)
            {
                XmlNodeList cells = rows[startIndex].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                int actualCellIndex = 0;
                for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                {
                    XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                    if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                        actualCellIndex =
                          int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                    //ColumnType autoDetectType =
                    //  getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));

                    if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        //dt.Columns.Add("Column" +
                        //  actualCellIndex.ToString(), autoDetectType.type);
                        dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString());
                        //columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //dt.Columns[actualCellIndex].DataType = autoDetectType.type;
                        //columns[actualCellIndex] = autoDetectType;
                    }

                    actualCellIndex++;
                }
            }
            //*************************
            //Load Data
            //*************************
            for (int i = startIndex; i < rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                XmlNodeList cells = rows[i].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                int actualCellIndex = 0;
                for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                {
                    XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                    if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                        actualCellIndex = int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                    XmlNode data = cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr);

                    if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        for (int ii = dt.Columns.Count; ii < actualCellIndex; ii++)
                        {
                            //dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(), typeof(string)); columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString());
                            //columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                        } // ii
                        //ColumnType autoDetectType = getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));
                        dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(),
                                       typeof(string));
                        // columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                    }
                    if (data != null)
                        row[actualCellIndex] = data.InnerText;

                    actualCellIndex++;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the official API first ([Microsoft Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

Comment: Isnt for reading .XLSX? I'm looking way to read files with XML extension. Tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298534.aspx   but said "File contains corrupted data."

Comment: Yes it is for reading OOXML containers. However, you have to do extra work to extract the raw XML and process it, so why not avoid all that and just process the container directly?

Comment: This API doesn't work for files saved from Excel as "XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml)", it's for "Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (*.xlsx)" files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
    var textReader = new XmlTextReader("...\\YourFile.xml");
    // Read until end of file
    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;
        // If node type us a declaration
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Declaration:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type is a comment
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Comment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Comment:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type us an attribute
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attribute:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type is an element
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type is an entity\
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Entity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entity:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type is a Process Instruction
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Entity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entity:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type a document
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.DocumentType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Document:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
        // if node type is white space
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WhiteSpace:" + textReader.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to get this: "ss:Index" atribute value ?

Comment: with Value property on this block if (nType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
        {var result = textReader.Value}

Comment: Not really... When I did that:   while (textReader.Read())    Console.WriteLine( textReader.NodeType +" -> "+textReader.Value );   Any attribute was listed

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class XMLtoDataTable
{
    private static ColumnType getDefaultType()
    {
        return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
    }

    struct ColumnType
    {
        public Type type;
        private string name;
        public ColumnType(Type type) { this.type = type; this.name = type.ToString().ToLower(); }
        public object ParseString(string input)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return DBNull.Value;
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                case "system.datetime":
                    return DateTime.Parse(input);
                case "system.decimal":
                    return decimal.Parse(input);
                case "system.boolean":
                    return bool.Parse(input);
                default:
                    return input;
            }
        }
    }


    private static ColumnType getType(XmlNode data)
    {
        string type = null;
        if (data.Attributes["ss:Type"] == null || data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value == null)
            type = "";
        else
            type = data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value;

        switch (type)
        {
            case "DateTime":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(DateTime));
            case "Boolean":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(Boolean));
            case "Number":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
            case "":
                decimal test2;
                if (data == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.InnerText) || decimal.TryParse(data.InnerText, out test2))
                {
                    return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
                }
            default://"String"
                return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
        }
    }

    public static DataSet ImportExcelXML(string fileName, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        Stream st = (Stream)sr.BaseStream;
        return ImportExcelXML(st, hasHeaders, autoDetectColumnType);
    }

    private static DataSet ImportExcelXML(Stream inputFileStream, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(inputFileStream));
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        nsmgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        foreach (XmlNode node in
          doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ss:Worksheet", nsmgr))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(node.Attributes["ss:Name"].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            XmlNodeList rows = node.SelectNodes("ss:Table/ss:Row", nsmgr);
            if (rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //*************************
                //Add Columns To Table from header row
                //*************************
                List<ColumnType> columns = new List<ColumnType>();
                int startIndex = 0;
                if (hasHeaders)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode data in rows[0].SelectNodes("ss:Cell/ss:Data", nsmgr))
                    {
                        columns.Add(new ColumnType(typeof(string)));//default to text
                        dt.Columns.Add(data.InnerText, typeof(string));
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                }
                //*************************
                //Update Data-Types of columns if Auto-Detecting
                //*************************
                if (autoDetectColumnType && rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[startIndex].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex =
                              int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        ColumnType autoDetectType =
                          getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" +
                              actualCellIndex.ToString(), autoDetectType.type);
                            columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Columns[actualCellIndex].DataType = autoDetectType.type;
                            columns[actualCellIndex] = autoDetectType;
                        }

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }
                }
                //*************************
                //Load Data
                //*************************
                for (int i = startIndex; i < rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[i].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex = int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        XmlNode data = cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr);

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            for (int ii = dt.Columns.Count; ii < actualCellIndex; ii++)
                            {
                                dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(), typeof(string)); columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                            } // ii
                            ColumnType autoDetectType =
                               getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(),
                                           typeof(string));
                            columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        }
                        if (data != null)
                            row[actualCellIndex] = data.InnerText;

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ExcelXMLtoDataTable
{
    private static ColumnType getDefaultType()
    {
        return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
    }

    struct ColumnType
    {
        public Type type;
        private string name;

        public ColumnType(Type type)
        {
            this.type = type; this.name = type.ToString().ToLower();

        }
        public object ParseString(string input)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return DBNull.Value;
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                case "system.datetime":
                    return DateTime.Parse(input);
                case "system.decimal":
                    return decimal.Parse(input);
                case "system.boolean":
                    return bool.Parse(input);
                default:
                    return input;
            }
        }
    }


    private static ColumnType getType(XmlNode data)
    {
        string type = null;
        //if (data == null)
        //    type = "";
        // else 
        if (data.Attributes["ss:Type"] == null || data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value == "")
            type = "";
        else
            type = data.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value;

        switch (type)
        {
            case "DateTime":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(DateTime));
            case "Boolean":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(Boolean));
            case "Number":
                return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
            case "":
                decimal test2;
                if (data == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.InnerText) || decimal.TryParse(data.InnerText, out test2))
                {
                    return new ColumnType(typeof(Decimal));
                    return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
                }
            default://"String"
                return new ColumnType(typeof(String));
        }
    }

    public static DataSet ImportExcelXML(string fileName, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        Stream st = (Stream)sr.BaseStream;
        return ImportExcelXML(st, hasHeaders, autoDetectColumnType);
    }
    private static DataSet ImportExcelXML(Stream inputFileStream, bool hasHeaders, bool autoDetectColumnType)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(inputFileStream));
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        nsmgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        foreach (XmlNode node in
          doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ss:Worksheet", nsmgr))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(node.Attributes["ss:Name"].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            XmlNodeList rows = node.SelectNodes("ss:Table/ss:Row", nsmgr);
            if (rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //*************************
                //Add Columns To Table from header row
                //*************************
                List<ColumnType> columns = new List<ColumnType>();
                int startIndex = 0;
                if (hasHeaders)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode data in rows[0].SelectNodes("ss:Cell/ss:Data", nsmgr))
                    {
                        columns.Add(new ColumnType(typeof(string)));//default to text
                        dt.Columns.Add(data.InnerText, typeof(string));
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                }
                //*************************
                //Update Data-Types of columns if Auto-Detecting
                //*************************
                if (autoDetectColumnType && rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[startIndex].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex =
                              int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        //ColumnType autoDetectType =
                        //  getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            //dt.Columns.Add("Column" +
                            //  actualCellIndex.ToString(), autoDetectType.type);
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString());
                            //columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //dt.Columns[actualCellIndex].DataType = autoDetectType.type;
                            //columns[actualCellIndex] = autoDetectType;
                        }

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }
                }
                //*************************
                //Load Data
                //*************************
                for (int i = startIndex; i < rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    XmlNodeList cells = rows[i].SelectNodes("ss:Cell", nsmgr);
                    int actualCellIndex = 0;
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        XmlNode cell = cells[cellIndex];
                        if (cell.Attributes["ss:Index"] != null)
                            actualCellIndex = int.Parse(cell.Attributes["ss:Index"].Value) - 1;

                        XmlNode data = cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr);

                        if (actualCellIndex >= dt.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            for (int ii = dt.Columns.Count; ii < actualCellIndex; ii++)
                            {
                                //dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(), typeof(string)); columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                                dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString());
                                //columns.Add(getDefaultType());
                            } // ii
                            //ColumnType autoDetectType = getType(cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data", nsmgr));
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + actualCellIndex.ToString(),
                                           typeof(string));
                            // columns.Add(autoDetectType);
                        }
                        if (data != null)
                            row[actualCellIndex] = data.InnerText;

                        actualCellIndex++;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }

}
```