Deserializing Excel XML file - attributes are not deserializing
I have this xml file, saved from Excel.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    ...
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Page1">
    ...
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>

And this model definition.
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Worksheet", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")]
public class Worksheet
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Workbook", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")]
public class Workbook
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Worksheet", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")]
    public List<Worksheet> Worksheet { get; set; }
}

I'm trying to deserialize xml two different ways.
With XmlNamespaceManager
var xml = File.ReadAllText("so.xml");
var nt = new NameTable();
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
mgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
mgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
mgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
mgr.AddNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");

var ctxt = new XmlParserContext(nt, mgr, "", XmlSpace.Default);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), null, ctxt);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Workbook));

var wb = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Workbook;
var ws = wb.Worksheet.First();
Console.WriteLine(ws.Name); //ws.Name is null

And without
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Workbook));
using var fs = new FileStream("so.xml", FileMode.Open);

var wb = serializer.Deserialize(fs) as Workbook;
var ws = wb.Worksheet.First();
Console.WriteLine(ws.Name); //ws.Name is null

In both cases the attribute Name is not available.
But by changing the namespace declaration xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" in xml and model to something else, the attributes become available.
How to get attribute values without changing namespace?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897082/how-to-read-excel-xml-c

It uses iterating XmlNode. I think that overkill for this solution.
Easier to change namespace declaration in xml, before parsing.

The problem is in the model. I made it an xml -> c# converter https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/xml-to-csharp
It added incorrect namespaces to elements.
Solution: specify an empty namespace for Worksheet.
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Worksheet", Namespace = "")]
